# z axis too long in 3dplot in sage

Tags: plot, sage, fuzzy-logic, z-axis

I'm trying to make this plot for the Łukasiewicz t-norm

[image: goal]

and I don't know how to make the z axis go only from 0 to 1,
mine goes from -1 to 1 and I need that flat area to be visible.

Now I have

```
def luka_tnorm(a, b):
    c = a + b - 1
    return max(c, 0)

plot3d(luka_tnorm(a, b), (a, 0, 1), (b, 0, 1))
```

My plot now looks like this

[image: my current plot]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sage: plot3d(luka_tnorm, (0, 1), (0, 1))
Launched html viewer for Graphics3d Object
sage: plot3d(luka_tnorm, (0, 1), (0, 1), mesh=True)
Launched html viewer for Graphics3d Object
```

Comment: thank you very much! it is so easy, why didnt I come up with that